# Creating a Google Login using Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, google-signin, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to create a Google Login option in a Grails project. I'm new to Grails and am using version 2.4.4 as this was the latest at the time of installing. After much searching of the Grails Plugins I've added the last 4 lines to my BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
    plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"

    // added these...
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
    compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4'
    compile ':spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1'

}
```

And I've added the following block to my Config.groovy file:

```
oauth {
providers {
    google {
        api = org.grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth.GoogleApi20 
        key = app id
        secret = secret key
        successUri = '/oauth/google/success'
        failureUri = '/oauth/google/error'
        callback = "${baseURL}/oauth/google/callback"
        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }
    debug = true
    connectTimeout = 5000
    receiveTimeout = 5000
}
```

I've also ran "grails s2-init-oauth" and created an "OAuthID" class. When I run my application, however, I get a error which says...

```
Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: java.lang.Boolean
```

Has anyone encountered this problem and can suggest a fix? Even an explanation of what is causing the error message in the first place would help me at this point?

Comment: Try refreshing dependencies command -  `grails refresh-dependencies`

Comment: Have tried that, thanks, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also created login using Google. For that I have use **Oauth Plugin**.

For that, in BuildConfig.groovy I have added

```
compile ":oauth:2.1.0"
```

In Config.groovy,

```
oauth {
    providers {
        google {
            api = org.scribe.builder.api.GoogleApi
            key = '583594517530-72ipieehn58c5160rvgdsodjgiifoedn.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            secret = 'pBtTg2j_EfanwNhuuAIDWW48'
            scope ='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
            callback = "http://localhost:8080/googleAuthen/oauth/google/callback"
            successUri = "http://localhost:8080/googleAuthen/oauthCallBack/google"

        }
    }
}
```

You can see full code in [this github repo](https://github.com/ramsharan065/googleOpenAuth).

The documentation for the Oauth plugin is [here](http://antony.github.io/grails-oauth-scribe/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your approach and it seems to work (so long as I use your key and secret), but doesn't this use version 1 which Google is phasing out next month?

Comment: Yes it uses oauth1. I haven't tried oauth2. Need to look on that.

Comment: I was able to get oauth2 "working" using the GoogleApi20 based on the code @Ramsharan supplied. I needed to make sure the callback URI ended in /oauth/google/callback so that the session key gets stored. I only got rid of the original error though by creating a brand new project and then editing the Build.Config file. I still don't know what is broken in the original project. The problem I have now is figuring out what to do with the token I've retrieved, the s2o tag libs aren't working but I guess that's another issue.

Comment: @user3042437 Thank you for that GoogleApi20.

Answer (score 0):

This was because you used debug = true in your configuration. That does not exist in the config properties.